# order array in order based by order in model and numerically

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I want to order this list by the order of what the selection has in the model. For instance, since VHS_ is the designated Name..all VHS_ items should appear first, but in numeral order. Then LEE_, JE_ and CHS_ (everything should flow underneath but in its own numerical order. JE_50 will appear above JE_59

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  selection:[{Name:"VHS_",Dept:"Truck",subjects:["_VHS_","LEE_","JE_","CHS_"]}],
    todos: [
      {
    "Name": "CHS_200_TL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
        {
    "Name": "VHS_600_TL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
  {
    "Name": "VHS_116_TL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
    {
    "Name": "VHS_613_TL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
  {
  "Name":"JE_50_OL_T62_TRUCK"
  },

  {
    "Name": "VHS_T10_OL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
    {
  "Name":"JE_59_OL_T62_TRUCK"
  },
      {
    "Name": "LEE_100_TL_L62_TRUCK"
  },
    ]
  },
  mounted:function(){
  this.arranges();
  },
  methods: {
  arranges: function() {
// Sort data
  todos.sort(b.Name,a.Name)
 
            },
}


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script> 
<div id="app">
<ul v-for="t in todos"><li>{{t.Name}}</li></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `todos` array should be resorted whenever `selection` changes you should use a computed property that will rerun automatically whenever any of it's dependencies (`selection`) changes.

```js
  computed: {
    sortedTodos() {
      // sort using a shallow copy
      return [...this.todos].sort((a, b) => {
        a = a.Name;
        b = b.Name;
        // get the index of a and b's subject code found in the selection array
        let aSubj = this.selection[0].subjects.findIndex((s) =>
          s.includes(a.split("_")[0])
        );
        let bSubj = this.selection[0].subjects.findIndex((s) =>
          s.includes(b.split("_")[0])
        );
        // if a and b start with same three character subject, sort by standard string comparison
        if (aSubj === bSubj) {
          return a.localeCompare(b);
        // else sort according to their index in the selection array
        } else {
          return aSubj - bSubj;
        }
      });
    },
  },
```

then use the computed property in your template

```html
<ul v-for="t in sortedTodos"><li>{{t.Name}}</li></ul>
```